# How to upload subtitles using API youtube v3 with vbasic

Tags: excel, vba, api, youtube, subtitle

i found examples in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/insert of code in java, php and python about how to upload files .srt using API YouTube v3. But i need to do that in visual basic (macros from excel). 
i have more than 3000 files srt. My channel has +650 videos, and i am translating every video to +10 languages. All the information is in a .xlsm file (excel witch macros), that's why i need the code in visual basic

Can someone show me a example of code i can use??

Comment: So you need VBA code to ...upload subtitles to Youtube? Using their API? Hmm - it may be easier to save the Excel file to a Python/Java/Php format, then upload with already existing code, than to code something from scratch.

Comment: [There is no client library for VB](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries), so you'll have to call the API directly.

Comment: i tried in java, but the code i found in the url i shared doesnt work

Comment: and i found code in vbasic about how to upload videos, so i guess it should be easy to found about how to upload subtitles

Comment: i am waiting for help yet....